# Is There Any Definitive List of Revisions and Retcons in the Star Wars Movies?

Tags: star-wars, retcon, revision

I remember seeing the original *Star Wars* on the first day it was released in my city (which, sadly, was a few weeks after it was released in many cities).  Being a young geek who could only get SF in books and once a week from *Star Trek* reruns, I saw it as many times as I could that summer and it was etched firmly on my brain.

Within a year or two there was a re-release.  I'm pretty sure this was **not** the re-release with footage of *The Empire Strikes Back* and a few friends and I noticed they had, at the time, added echo effects with Luke and Leia in the chasm.

That was my first experience with movies being retconned.  As we all know, along the way, Lucas has made a number of changes to the original trilogy, mostly to the original *Star Wars* (including adding "Episode IV" to the title).

Is there a list of what changes, revisions, and retcons have been done to the *Star Wars* movies and when they've been done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While they describe their own list as "partial", the most complete one I've seen is still the one at [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases) as it compares the various versions.

But [this list of SE changes](http://savestarwars.com/specialeditionchanges.html) is also really well done as it includes visual comparisons of the original and SE versions of [A New Hope](https://plus.google.com/photos/102542760950977079734/albums/5514974191245813441?banner=pwa), [The Empire Strikes Back](https://plus.google.com/photos/102542760950977079734/albums/5525747538664147553?banner=pwa), and [Return of the Jedi](https://plus.google.com/photos/102542760950977079734/albums/5528361230751063825?banner=pwa). It also includes a categorized [XLS of changes to ANH](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0An9BAfxfK2_odHVaV2o0cUxKU0pxOTNnNmtyVm8waHc&hl=en_US#gid=0), but sadly does not include documents for the other movies. Sadder, still, is the fact that it was never updated for the newer 2006 or 2011 edits.

[StarWars.com](http://starwars.com/news/saga_bluray_restoration.html) has a nice writeup about some of the changes for the 2011 versions, but is incomplete.

Comment: Unfortunately, the savestarwars.com domain has expired, so that second link is dead.