# When were the edits to the Star Wars films made?

Tags: star-wars, chronological-order

As many a *Star Wars* fan knows, over the years George Lucas made changes to the original trilogy. The most commonly debated is "Who shot first?"

I am just looking for the timeline on when the edits were made, not a list of the edits (as seen in this [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39892/is-there-any-definitive-list-of-revisions-and-retcons-in-the-star-wars-movies)) nor a list of all the releases. I have seen this [list on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases), but my feeble brain can not discern the information I am looking for.

To clarify, I am talking about story line edits (e.g. added, deleted, or changed scenes or dialogue.) Cosmetic edits like coloring or lighting are not as big of a deal to me.

To give an example I would be looking for:

- 1977: Theatrical Release
- 19XX: Edits, Round 1
- 19XX: Edits, Round 2
- ETC...

Help me, Stack Exchange, you're my only hope!

Comment: The only thing that we *really* need to know is that "Team Negative One" has a restored original theatrical release. *::Sigh::* Pure, liquid nostalgia. And better than any of the 'improved' versions.

Comment: Wait, what's this team negative one of which you speak???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While Wookieepedia is a great resource for in-universe information, to be honest [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_changes_in_Star_Wars_re-releases) is probably better in this regard for tracking versions.

Some minor changes were made fairly early on, like adding the title "Episode IV: A New Hope" to the first film - it was only added after it was clear there would be more episodes. The big changes didn't start until later...

- 1997: Special Editions. These were the ones that really started the whole ball rolling, replacing old FX shots with CGI, editing in Greedo shooting at Han, adding the Jabba scene to Episode IV, Luke screaming as he fell at the end of Episode V, the musical number in Episode VI, and so on. After the release of the prequels, we got...
- 2004: DVD release. More FX changes, recolouring (and miscolouring), added new dialogue, removing some of the previous changes, editing the Han/Greedo sequence again.
- 2011: Complete collection blu-ray release. More changes that it's hard to keep track of. Vader now shouts "NOOOOOO!" while throwing Palpatine down the shaft (because everyone loved it so much in Revenge of the Sith).

This is just a brief rundown, of course - there are a LOT of changes. The source linked above gives a fairly complete rundown.

Comment: There are 29 "minor changes" before the title was changed. I'm almost certain Skooba was asking about those and not just the main releases.
The 1985 VHS release has sound and visual edits done to it;
the 1993 definitive edition has changes that weren't mention;
Episode V had a list of things done before the 1997 special editions, followed by those listed.
The source however doesn't date the early 29 changes for Episode IV or the 30+ for Episode V.

Comment: @Edlothiad Thanks for the comment. It got me thinking of what I was really after. I added to the question... I am really looking for when the story was changed.

Comment: @Werrf, well if this is the answer you're looking for, then don't stop me, but of the "minor changes" mentioned a few are dialogue changes and such

Comment: @Edlothiad It sounds like you should post another answer. I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @DCShannon, they're all from the wiki link in Werrf's answer, and I couldn't find dates

Comment: Woops, sorry Werrf, I meant @Skooba earlier

Comment: Didn't Darth Vader get a head transplant?